# Is there a pythonic way of referring to the iterators variable names inside of the for loop?

Tags: python, design-patterns, syntax

Below is a code snippet:

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.next = None
```

...

```
val = carry
for l in filter(None, [l1, l2]):
    val += l.val
    l = l.next
```

l1 and l2 are two linked lists. If a list is empty it is set to *None* such that the loop only processes a linked list if it has not been completely traversed. I want to use the loop to prevent code duplication. **The issue is on line four, where upon an iteration of the loop neither l1 or l2 are updated with the next node of the list but l is instead.** Does anyone know of any nice patterns to fix this issue? Apologies if this question has been asked before but I do not know of the correct terminologies to search for an answer. Perhaps defining a separate function or an anonymous function would be the best way to go?

Answer (score 0):

When you do something like `l = l.next`, you're just changing where the name `l`
points to. If you make a linked list class wrapping the list nodes, you'll be
able to mutate the linked list object, without reference to the name you
assigned to it earlier.

I have added some methods for demonstration purposes.

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, x, next=None):
        self.val = x
        self.next = next

    @classmethod
    def from_values(cls, values):
        try:
            first_val = next(values)
            return cls(first_val, cls.from_values(values))
        except StopIteration:
            return None

    def __iter__(self):
        yield self.val
        if self.next is not None:
            yield from self.next

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, values):
        self.head = ListNode.from_values(iter(values))

    def __bool__(self):
        return bool(self.head)

    def __str__(self):
        if self.head is None:
            return "<>"
        return "<{}>".format(", ".join(str(i) for i in self.head))

l1 = LinkedList([])
l2 = LinkedList([1, 2, 3])
print(l1)
print(l2)
for l in filter(None, [l1, l2]):
    l.head= l.head.next
print(l1)
print(l2)
```

With output:

```
<>
<1, 2, 3>
<>
<2, 3>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you're trying to generalize this code in an awkward way. I'd give `ListNode` an `__iter__` method (or something similar), then just use that:

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.next = None

    def __iter__(self):
        cur_node = self

        while cur_node:
            yield cur_node.val
            cur_node = cur_node.next
```

Once you've done that and list nodes can be iterated, you can just pass `l1` and `l2` to `sum`:

```
l1_sum = sum(l1)
l2_sum = sum(l2)
```